# global notification in ios when push message

Tags: android, ios

I have developed an android app and now I am trying to implement the same one in IOS but not easy. Please Somebody help me.

Below is my implementation in android.

[image]

as you see in the picture when a push notification arrives in the foreground state,
the "POP notification on the top" is shown where ever I am in the app. It's possible because I have developed it with one activity and multiple fragments that when a notification arrives, I can control it in the activity that whatever fragment I see, I can pop the notification.

But in IOS, due to my poor skill, It's not easy...

let me show you my current IOS structure which is under the designation.

[image]

as you see it, it has one tab bar controller which has 5 menu

and each menu has a navigation controller, and each of them also has a view controller.

In this structure, can I implement the notification like the first image?
or should I change the structure?..

currently, I don't know what I should study for solving this.. please let me know.

Comment: You can present the pop up using the root view controller, which is your tab bar controller in this case

Comment: can you let me know a very small example?.. 
I can't feel it yet and if possible swift code programmatically dude.

Comment: and you know, in the list view if we click something we need to move to a single detail view page, in this situation, can I pop the notification too?

Comment: Unfortunately while it isn't a lot of code, it isn't a small amount of code either; too much to add to an answer here.  There are also several open source "toast" frameworks that you might like to look at.

Comment: Thanks for your answer what I want to know was the word "TOAST", I have searched about it and I think I found the solution I need and can use

Comment: repeatly, Thanks you